# How to use an unknown number of queries?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's assume that I have a List of playing card objects whose values are stored in a delimited string containing the value, suit, and color. Eg. "king:heart:red"
Admittedly, a bad design choice but just go with it for the purpose of the question.

I could write the following linq queries:

```
var result = from c in cards
    where c.Contains("king")
    select c;

var result = from c in cards
    where c.Contains("king")
    where c.Contains("red")
    select c;

var result = from c in cards
    where c.Contains("king")
    where c.Contains("queen")
    where c.Contains("jack")
    select c;
```

The first one would return the four kings
The second would return the two red queens
And the third would return all 12 picture cards.

What if the *where.Contains* queries were based on user input and could have many more options?  How would I write the code to deal with an unknown number of *where.Contains* queries?

​

Comment: "How would I write the code to deal with an unknown number of where.Contains queries?" you would use a `params string [] queries` as parameter in your method and you would use `Where(x => queries.Any(q => x.Contains(q))`

Comment: 1) "The second would return the two red queens" is it a typo or are you trying to confuse us? 2) "And the third would return all 12 picture cards." no it would not. it will filter for kings then it will filter these results for queen and return an empty collection because they are no queens in the kings collection. So you will get an entirely empty result

Comment: _"What if the where.Contains queries were based on user input and could have many more options?"_ The main issue here is the different between `and` and `or`. When I input "king" and "queen", it may be obvious that I mean "king or queen", but when I input "king" and "red", do I mean "king or red", "king and red", or maybe even "king XOR red"? This leads to a lot of complexity that is usually not worth the effort. I suspect that you're trying to overgeneralize your filtering.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. You really should take your time and respond to the comments and question that are asked in the comments. They help to clarify your problem and improve the quality of this post. Because a question is meant not only to help 1 person who asked it, but it is meant to help future visitors of this page with the same problem. I guess you have already found more than once a solution on SO and you will find more in future. The only reason you could find it is the quality of the posts and answers ;) please help to maintain that level of quality

Answer (score 0):

Out of the top of my head something like this would be possible with entity framework:

```cs
var inPut = new List<string> { "king", "red", "jack" };

var result = from c in cards
    where inPut.Any(x => c.Contains(x))
    select c;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    var cards= new string[] { "king:red:jack", "king:heart:red" };
    
    var strArray = new string[] { "heart" };

    var result = GetCards(cards,strArray);

public IEnumerable<string> GetCards(string[] cards,  string[] strArray)
{
    return cards.Where(c=> IfContains(c,strArray)).ToArray();
}

public bool IfContains(string card, string[] strArray)
{
    var cardArray =card.Split(":");
    return cardArray.Any(c => strArray.Contains(c));
}
```

test result

```
[ "king:heart:red" ]
```

or if you have string from an  user input

```
var input="king,red";
var strArr=input.Split(',');
var result=GetCards(cards,strArr);
```

test result

```
[ "king:heart:red","king:red:jack"]
```

Comment: unfortunately you have it reversed. your code looks for whether `"king"` contains `"king:heart:red"` the method returns an empty collection. [Have a look](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qH8AQp)

Comment: @MongZhu Thanks, pls check my updated answer

Comment: please check yourself. The question is asking explicitly about the format: `"king:heart:red"`. your answer does not provide a solution for that. The first query in the question returns an entire card. your code would only return the matched key word.... the aim is to return the entire information about a card like: `"king:heart:red"`

Comment: @MongZhu Thank you very much. I never read questions carefully and always miss something. I updated my answer again.

Comment: ok you got it, have an upvote